# How to have different spellings of the same word in one entry in a glossary?

Tags: glossaries

So my question is probably naive and I'm sorry about that. I'm a beginner in Latex and I would like to create a glossary for a text in old french. A word can have multiple different spellings, and I'd like my glossary to have all the spellings written in one entry, always followed by the numbers of page (ideally the numbers of line but that would be for another question, I guess). Do you know how I could do that? I think I could achieve this with the keys user1 user2 and so on but I don't really know how.

My document would be like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

    \usepackage{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \newglossaryentry{Lorem}{name={lorem},%
    description={ipsum},% And I would need other spellings like Lores, loret... 
    }

    \begin{document}

    \gls{Lorem} ipsum lores loret.

   \printglossaries

    \end{document}
```

thank you so much!

Comment: Yes ! Thank you, sorry about that. It would end like that

\printglossaries \end{document} I'm really new to this. Thank you for the welcoming !